# dropdown wont drop on mobile screen

Tags: dropdown

I have a dropdown which i need to keep the url intact on the parent so i put disable class, but when i open it on my mobile, it immediately goes to the url and it wont drop. Here's the code.

```
<div class="row">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default polo" role="navigation">    
        <div class="navbar-header">       
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle pull-left" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#polo-nav">          
            <span class="sr-only">
        </span>          
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>          
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>          
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>       
            </button>
        </div>    
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="polo-nav">       
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">                    
                <li class="dropdown"><a href="<?=base_url()?>polo.html" class="dropdown-toggle polo-sub disabled" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="" data-delay="0">Accueil</a>             
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">                
                        <li><a href="<?=base_url()?>polo/activities.html">Activites</a></li>                                      
                        <li><a href="<?=base_url()?>polo/infrastructure.html">Infrastructures</a></li>                                      
                    </ul>          
                </li>          
                <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle polo-sub" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="" data-delay="0">Tournois</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">                     
                        <?php
                            $this->db->select('tou_name,id');
                            $this->db->where('trashed',0);
                            $this->db->from('tbl_tournament');
                            $query = $this->db->get();
                            foreach ($query->result() as $row)
                            {
                                ?>                                
                                <li><a href="<?=base_url()?>tournois/jeux/<?=$row->id?>/<?=$this->mlfunction->changetodash($row->tou_name)?>.html"><?=$row->tou_name?></a></li>  
                                <?php
                            }
                        ?>                                      
                    </ul>    
                </li>            
                <li><a class="polo-sub" href="<?=base_url()?>leclub.html">Le Club</a></li>       
                <li><a class="polo-sub" href="<?=base_url()?>schedule.html">Calendrier</a></li>
                <li><a class="polo-sub" href="<?=base_url()?>polo/tarifs.html">Tarifs</a></li>        
                <li><a class="polo-sub" href="<?=base_url()?>polo/partenaires.html">Partenaires</a></li>      
                <li><a class="polo-sub" href="<?=base_url()?>actualities/actualities.html">Actualites</a></li>      
                <li><a class="polo-sub" href="<?=base_url()?>polo/contact.html">Contact</a></li>   
            </ul> 
        </div> 
    </nav> 
</div>
```